# getting this error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

Tags: flutter, gradle, jvm, java-11

Hello am building a flutter apk using vscode but I get the error below, any help on how to go about it. Did a research but am getting no solution. I have configured JAVA_HOME well in gradle setting in android studio yet gradle am still getting the same error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\cs\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-all\2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    
    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:51)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:263)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:255)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:108)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:95)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:90)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.updateFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:51)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.update(SimpleStateCache.java:87)
        
    
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Turning off the Mobile-Hotspot worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What worked for me on `Windows`;

- I opened task manager (with `Ctrl+Alt+Delete`).
- Stopped and/or ended processes for all running `openJDKs` (like any `java.exe`).
- Just re-run `Gradle` and done! Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 30):

That's because you start debugging while hotspot is active in your device
All you need to do is :

1. Open your Task Manager `alt+ctrl+delete`
2. End-Task of all open-JDKs
3. turn of mobile-hotspot
4. start debug again
5. Keep Coding

Comment: Thanks. By turn off mobile hotsport i solved my problem

Comment: Oh, so much unexpected. mobile hotspot.
In Windows, `taskkill /IM java.exe /F` to kill all java.exe

Answer (score 9):

I've had encountered the same problem before, what I did was just simply turn off the mobile hotspot on my **laptop**, run and debug again then it works like a charm! [turn off this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4lQj.png)

p/s: I turn on the mobile hotspot to share the internet connection with my other laptop at that time, so you just need to turn it off then it should be okay after that.

Just simply go to Settings > Network & internet > Mobile Hotspot, then turn off the mobile hotspot if you are turning it on at that time.

Answer (score 4):

I disabled Mobile hotspot in my windows pc , then tried build it didn't worked for me.
then i just logged out from and logged in tried build again , its worked!

Answer (score 3):

when you look at task manager there is many open JDK platformBinary open and running in the same time, i recommend you to restart your laptop and it will be normally again. i recommend this to you cause this was work on me.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows open task manager `Ctrl + Alt + Supr` then end the tasks for `adb.exe`.
That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was connected to having an active VPN-Connection. Disabling the VPN solved this issue for me.

Comment: And it was only needed while building, after that you can restart it. Any way for me to split tunnel this or set some DNS? I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above methods resolved the issue when it occurred for the second time this week on my Windows 10 Pro 22H2.

I attempted to deactivate Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, VPN, terminated adb.exe, and any Java or JDK processes. I also tried restarting my computer, but none of these actions resolved the issue.

However, I found a solution that worked for me by following the steps outlined [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-94/Revise-IDE-directory-locking-mechanism-dont-fail-startup-if-all-ports-in-range-are-taken-limited-network-due-to-firewall-VPN) :

**PROBLEM 1**
If all the 50 ports between 6942 and 6991 are reserved, taken by the other apps or firewall doesn't allow IDE to bind on them, startup fails with the below exception:

**WORKAROUND**: run the following commands in the Administrator console (cmd.exe):

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16383
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=49152 num=16383
```

If the above doesn't help, please try these commands instead:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

For macOS users with "Can't assign requested address" error:

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332407/how-to-change-ifconfig-lo0, this command should help:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1
```

EXCEPTION:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more

-----
JRE 11.0.6+8-b765.25 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Users\yatwi\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\Rider\ch-0\201.6668.197\jbr
```

**PROBLEM 2**
Unable to start the IDE with a network limited due to firewall/VPN: See IDEA-253939 for example.

**WORKAROUND**
Add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the IDE's `.vmoptions` file and start the IDE.
Check here to find the `.vmoptions` file: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869 .

EXCEPTION:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServerKt.multiThreadEventLoopGroup(BuiltInServer.kt:144)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServerKt.access$multiThreadEventLoopGroup(BuiltInServer.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer$Companion.start(BuiltInServer.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.start(BuiltInServer.kt)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lambda$lockAndTryActivate$2(SocketLock.java:171)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:175)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:142)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:146)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:142)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:173)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:476)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:468)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 31 more

-----
JRE 11.0.8+10-b1129.2 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o.
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 203.5251.39\jbr
```

Or caused by `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect` in last part.

Comment: `net stop/start winnat` actually worked for me, everything else suggested in this and similar entries failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1: Just turn off your internet connection from both your laptop and mobile app.

2: Then close Android Studio project and reopen, this worked for me.